# No admin styles after following tutorial

Tags: python, django, django-cms

I just walked through [the installation guide for Django CMS](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/getting_started/integrate.html) and I'm unfortunately not seeing the Admin styles shown.

Here's what I see:

[image]

Here's what's pictured in the tutorial:

http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/_images/basic-page-form.png

It appears that for some reason, the admin styles aren't kicking in.

Here's my `settings.py`:

```
"""
Django settings for projectname project.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/
"""

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))

# True base path of the entire project, ie directory of setup.py
PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..'))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'things'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

SITE_ID = 1


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    # Default
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # Pipeline
    'pipeline',
    # Django CMS
    'mptt',
    'menus',
    'sekizai',
    'djangocms_admin_style',
    'cms'
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    # Django CMS
    'cms.middleware.user.CurrentUserMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.page.CurrentPageMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.toolbar.ToolbarMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.language.LanguageCookieMiddleware',
)

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
    "django.core.context_processors.debug",
    "django.core.context_processors.i18n",
    "django.core.context_processors.media",
    "django.core.context_processors.request",
    "django.core.context_processors.static",
    "django.core.context_processors.tz",
    "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
    'sekizai.context_processors.sekizai',
    'cms.context_processors.cms_settings',
)

MIGRATION_MODULES = {
    'cms': 'cms.migrations_django',
    'menus': 'menus.migrations_django',
}

ROOT_URLCONF = 'projectname.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'projectname.wsgi.application'

# Pipeline
# http://django-pipeline.readthedocs.org
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'pipeline.storage.PipelineCachedStorage'

PIPELINE_COMPILERS = (
    'pipeline.compilers.less.LessCompiler'
)

PIPELINE_CSS = {

}

PIPELINE_JS = {

}

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGES = [
    ('en-us', 'English'),
]

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/static-files/

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, "media")
MEDIA_URL = "/media/"

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, "static")
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, "templates"),
)

CMS_TEMPLATES = (
    ('template_1.html', 'Template One'),
)
```

And, for reference, here are my URLs:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import include, url, patterns
from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^', include('cms.urls')),
) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

What have I missed that causes the admin to not get the right styles?

Comment: By the way, just checked the browser cache, doesn't seem to be responsible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `INSTALLED_APPS`, you have to put `'django.contrib.admin'` below`'djangocms_admin_style'`, like:

```
...
'djangocms_admin_style',
'django.contrib.admin',
...
```

As the [django-cms documentation](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/getting_started/integrate.html#installing-and-configuring-django-cms-in-your-django-project) says:

```
'djangocms_admin_style',  # for the admin skin. You **must** add 'djangocms_admin_style' in the list **before** 'django.contrib.admin'.
```

After that, the style can be displayed correctly.